# How to find multiple centroids in a binary image in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, centroid

I'm aware that OpenCV can find the centroid of a binary image, but is there any existing algorithm that can find multiple centroids in a binary image? For example, if I set the number of centroids detected in the binary image to be 4, I should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: You may want to make the outside of the black figure black, so that you only have 4 white dots on a black background.  However that is not necessary.  You can then either get the contours and loop over each contour finding the ones with a certain range of areas and then find each centroid. Or you can use connected components, which can also provide the contours. The former is probably easier. See the OpenCV documentation for those approaches and/or search this forum for examples.

Comment: What would be the definition of "multiple centroids"? It is difficult to understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: related https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/56565/are-there-any-algorithms-for-solid-polygon-clustering

Comment: @fmw42 I believe the white dots are there just for illustration purposes. The idea is to have a binary object and define a number of centroids to be computed for it. Then the function magically identifies them at those locations.

Comment: If this is a pixel image, you can perform a clustering algorithm like k-means, and use each pixel as an element of the data set

Comment: @Andreas The centroid is the point that minimizes the sum of squared distances to all other points. So one possible definition of multiple centroids is a set of n points yᵢ that minimizes Σₓ minᵢ || x - yᵢ ||²

Comment: @JohnGowers I see your point, but any implementation of this basically boils down to an optimization problem that you will only be able to solve partially. If anything, I would look for some triangulation (e.g. Voronoi) that can derive basic parts of the overall shape, and then calculate the centroids for those parts.